# Get route {id} value in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I known if I have something like `/controller/action/{id}` I can access id as a function parameter. But how would I access it via the view without using the viewbag?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass that function parameter to the View as part of a model.  The model can be staticly or dynamically typed.  The example code below demonstrates how to pass the value as a property on a dynamic model.

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    dynamic model = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    model.Id = id;
    return View(model);

}
```

You would access this value in the view as follows:

```
@Model.Id
```

Comment: Thats cool. +1. But the same issue with viewbag, I need to typecast it (and assign it to somewhere). I guess there is no native way outside of the controller

Comment: can you be more specific with what you are trying to accomplish?  I'll give you a hand. Casting is not a problem with the code I provided.

Comment: Nothing other then what i said. Theres no 'problem' except with myself. I'm very lazy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the URL to get the ID when in the view:

```
var id = Request.Url.LocalPath.SubString(LastIndexOf("/",Request.Url.LocalPath)+1);
```

Comment: I won't use that. What if I do `/id?ping=pong`. int.parse would blow up. ATM I can't remember what to use to get just the path (without query) with a uri.

Comment: Just use Request.Url.LocalPath that would ignore querystring.

Comment: Looks correct. Ok its decent enough so i'll +1 but wont accept until later. `Request.Url.LocalPath.Substring(Request.Url.LocalPath.LastIndexOf("/")+1)`

Comment: oh crap, i figured it out accidentally when trying to figure out where the param goes when i do `RenderBody("form.cshtml", "My random sz")`

Answer (score 0):

It will be put directly into the `ViewBag.id` or you can access it via `ViewData["id"]`. hey seem like the same object